# ReactJS: Use setState at the end of a if statement inside a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

As the title says, I am trying to a use **setState** inside of an **if** statement that is set inside a **function** and I'm having some issues.

I am trying to crete a series of **Tab** components, which take a function as **inline style** to determine if they should be visible or hidden. However, before I do the **return** for that function, I want to **setState** for the index of the rendered tab.

```
    <Tab label="Tab 1" {...a11yProps(0)} style={displayTab(dataGames.length, 0)} />;
    <Tab label="Tab 2" {...a11yProps(1)} style={displayTab(dataTvShows.length, 1)} />;
    <Tab label="Tab 3" {...a11yProps(2)} style={displayTab(dataMovies.length, 2)} />;
    <Tab label="Tab 4" {...a11yProps(3)} style={displayTab(dataSpotify.length, 3)} />;
```

Here is my **displayTab** function:

```
  const displayTab = (dataLength:number, index:number) => {
    if(dataLength === 0) {
      return {display:"none"};
    }else{
      setTabIndex(index) //<----- this causes the Error!
      return {display:"flex"};
    }
  }
```

However, whenever I run this, I get an error related to **infinite render**. My tabindex is just a simple number state   `const [tabIndex, setTabIndex] = useState<number>(0);`

The Tab component is a part of Material UI.

How can I call my **setTabIndex** before I return `{display:'flex'}` inside my function?

Comment: You're getting infinite render because the `displayTab` function is called on render, within it, you call `setTab` which causes a further render. See where I'm going?

Comment: @Ameer yes, I know _why_ this is happening. I'm trying to find a way around it.

Comment: Why are you doing that from inside the displayTab function? You should use a useEffect do do this. useEffect is where you should make side effects

Comment: @RaduDiță maybe, I'm not sure how to make it inside a useEffect hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `setTabIndex` in JSX isn't ideal, you know why? Your component renders and as soon as `setTabIndex` is called it changes your `tabIndex` state and then it `re-renders`, thus ending in a loop.

I'm guessing that you're trying to keep an active index in the `tabIndex` state, right?

You need to set the new tabIndex when a tab is clicked.

You need a handler for that, see `handleChange` below.

```
const [tabIndex, setTabIndex] = React.useState(0);

const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newTabIndex: number) => {
  setTabIndex(newTabIndex);
};
```

And then you should pass that handler to your `Tabs`' onChange prop. `Tabs`' value prop should receive `tabIndex` state.

```
<Tabs value={tabIndex} onChange={handleChange}
```

Finally your `displayTab` should calculate the styles like this.

```
const displayTab = (dataLength: number) => {
  return { 
    display: dataLength === 0 ? 'none' : 'flex' 
  }
}
```

and should be called like this

```
<Tab label="Tab 1" {...a11yProps(0)} style={displayTab(dataGames.length)} />
```

Comment: Well this does make sense but your initial tabIndex value is 0 and if you have 1 tab with data, it will not be rendered initially.

Comment: I'm trying to understand when do you exactly want to render a tab or not, maybe your displayTab function shouldn't take in account the current index. I mean passing only `dataLength` as an argument and your condition should be `dataLength === 0 ? 'none' : 'flex'`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you trying to achieve, but try below code

```
  const displayTab = (dataLength:number, index:number) => {
    if(dataLength === 0) {
      return {display:"none"};
    }else{
       if(index !== tabIndex) setTabIndex(index) 
      return {display:"flex"};
    }
  }
```

Comment: This won't work as setState won't do a re-render if the value is the same. So your condition does nothing

Answer (score 0):

if you use a ternary operator like this it will only hide of stated tab and other able to display.

```
    const [tab,setTab] = useState(0)

    {["dataGames","dataTvShows","dataMovies","dataSpotify"].map((data,index)=>{
    return <Tab label={`Tab ${index}`} {...a11yProps(index)} style={tab === index ?{display:"none"}:{display:"flex"}} />;
    })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not put the `seTabIndex` in the `displayTab` function

```
const handleChange = (event, value) => {
  setTabIndex(index)
};
```

```
 <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
      <Tab label="Item One" />
      <Tab label="Item Two" />
      <Tab label="Item Three" />
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score -1):

you should not use setState in this case, it's really bad way to solve the problem